# How to connect a 5.1 DVD Home Theater Speaker to PC?

Tags: audio, dvd, speakers, rca

Recently I found an old DVD player in my garage. It seems like the speakers work fine, but can I connect it to my PC instead of CD/USB? I want them work as my PC speakers.

The input:
[image]

Am I able to connect **RCA to laptop cable** to the DVD player input?

[image: RCA to laptop cable]

Comment: The DVD player is unlikely to decode to 5.1 from a stereo analog input. It might send some signal to the centre & sub, but you'll find that out once you connect it all up. What you won't get is 5.1.

Comment: @Tetsujin -  that depends on whether the DVD receiver supports Dolby Pro-Logic II through the AUX input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a 3.5mm jack to phono cable. A simple internet search will provide a bountiful supply of purchasing options.

The cable you have includes a video input (yellow), you could use that cable and leave the yellow plug disconnected.

Comment: [cable](https://ibb.co/3fSN6dk)do you mean this cable ?

Comment: The one you linked includes video, you don't need the video part of the cable. As I said in my answer, leave the yellow plug disconnected or buy a 3.5mm Jack to phono cable.

Comment: Alright ! thanks for your help. I found a cable without the video (red and white only)

Comment: @Johnnyyy if I have helped, please feel free to up-vote the answer and/or mark is at the correct answer.